# how to pass a NS Basic Array to static C++ dll

Tags: c++, static-libraries, nsbasic

I need to pass a byte array from NS Basic to a static C++ dll.

in NS Basic, I define the function like this to static dll.

```
Declare "Function myFunc Lib ""dllLib.dll""(ByVal data As Byte()) As Long"
Buffer = Array(0,1,2,3)

'call the function
myFunc(Buffer)
```

For this, I would like to know what should be the signature of the static C++ function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long myFunc(unsigned char* buffer);
```

You may also need to pass in the size of the array a second parameter -

```
long myFunc(unsigned char* buffer, int size);
```